# Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function at another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I could not fix ajax error on the site.

> Error : Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function at Hei

My code are below.

Where am I making mistakes?

solutions in other posts did not help

`jquery-3.3.1.js` added removed

`jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js` added removed

`jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` added removed

But the error continues

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/custom.fle_upload.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        Hei();
    });

    function Hei() {
        var tbl = $('#dvHei');
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: '/Hei/getHei',
            contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html'
        }).success(function (result) {
            tbl.empty().append(result);
        }).error(function () {

        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you check to see if your local file matches jQuery from some CDN? Or even just use a CDN link instead, we can't verify the error existing like this.

Comment: the function `Hei()` should be inside of the `jQuery(document).ready( function ($ ){... )}`

Comment: Check browser console, jquery file found or not.

Comment: @Yair.R no, that's not necessary. And it's unrelated to the error, anyway

Comment: Please stop using `async:false`. It causes a bad user experience (freezes the browser's UI during the AJAX request) and also many browsers have already deprecated it, so you can expect it to stop working in future. It's not necessary and should not be used in new code. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ says "As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done()."

Comment: Also, consult http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ especially where it says "Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead." and then amend your code accordingly (replace .success() and .error() with .done() and .fail() respectively.

Comment: Another thing, jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js is not required for this particular bit of code to work. It's something related to ASP.NET MVC applications specifically.

Comment: Lastly, try changing `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {` to or `jQuery(document).ready(function () {` or just the shorthand `$(function() {`. There should be no need to define the $ - jQuery has done it already.

Comment: Although, it must be said, the code above does not on its own generate the stated error. See http://jsfiddle.net/d7eq8uhg/ - it generates a lot of other errors (due to the things I've already mentioned), but not that one. So I assume maybe your jQuery file is not being loaded correctly. Check your URL in the `<script` tag and that the file exists in that location. Obviously I cannot reproduce what's on your server so I used a CDN instead. And as a bonus, here's a fixed version removing the various problems I've mentioned: http://jsfiddle.net/d7eq8uhg/2/

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community.  Sometimes, the issue could be the current scope for some reason.  I've done the following without any issues, unless something was "repackaging" the "$" pointer to something else:

```
function Hei() {
    var tbl = $('#dvHei');
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: '/Hei/getHei',
        contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html'
    }).success(function (result) {
        tbl.empty().append(result);
    }).error(function () {

    });
 }

//Same as document ready
$(function() {
   Hei();
});
```

If that doesn't work you can try this to see if it recognizes tbl as a jQuery object, as a way of debugging the issue?

```
var tbl = $('#dvHei');
alert(tbl.length);
$.ajax({
```